# How to get placemark info from static kml

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-earth, map-basic

I want to get information from static kml file or mapinfo tab file i.e I have a kml/mapinfo tab file that i open on google earth/mapinfo and it shows multiple placemarks but i want to get coordinates of all the placemarks that lie within 1km circle from my required single placemark. How it can be possilble on google eatrh or mapbasic code?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a basic "point in polygon" analysis function available in most GIS software, but not in Google Earth or Maps.  If you know how to use the free QGIS, you could do it in there, though the steps required are somewhat complex if you're never used GIS software before.  You'll need to bring in your KML, generate a new file with the single placemark and generate a circular "buffer" at the desired distance, and then select the features in the KML which overlap with the buffer.  And you'll need to manage projections to make it all work correctly.

If you have a large enough KML to warrant the work, or need to do this many times, then it's probably worth figuring out how to do it with GIS software.  If it's only a small number of placemarks, and you only need to do it one or a few times, then get Google Earth Pro (it's free), use the Measure tool to draw a 1km circle, and manually select the points inside it.

Comment: actually i want to do it via code that i automatically get all points within 1 km circle from my given point? is it possible through GIS...and how i can use / start as i am newbie in this

Comment: What programming languages do you know? You can do something like this using javascript and the Google Maps API + Fusion Tables API.  Or you could use one of many Python based packages, with or without QGIS... logs of options.